# Node JS : running the file continuously in background

Tags: node.js

i am running the node js file as given below,

```
node filename.js
```

but when exit the terminal in ubuntu, the running process gets terminated.

but i need run that **filename.js** continuously in the background even when i exit the terminal in ubuntu.

How can i do it?

Comment: Have a look at `screen`.

Comment: I guess you need something like cron -  a deamon process which runs in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spawn detached

```
$ node filename.js &
```

or - if stuff gets more complex - use e.g. forever: https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: ok lipp, how can i stop the script if i execute the command **node filename.js &**

Comment: using ps (or pgrep node) and kill using the process id. pgrep node --> 35; kill 35

Answer (score 0):

You need to daemonize the process, for that you can use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).